# Extract text from sections of a Latex exported PDF, using Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, latex

I have PDFs of Scientific research papers which were written in Latex. 
Each research paper has sections such as "Introduction, "Related work" , etc and I wanted to extract the text under each section separately.

[image: Sample Image of a PDF with sections such as "Abstract" and "Introduction"]

This PDF has sections "Abstract" and "Introduction" on page 1.
For "Abstract" section, I'd like to retrieve the text in italicts. For "Introduction" I want all those paragraphs in its section.

If I had the Latex source file I could have done some data-mining and extracted the text based on \section{} keywords

Hence I tried a few ways in Python3 such as converting pdf to latex [[link]](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/8503/how-to-convert-pdf-to-latex) but the softwares suggested are either not compatible with my system(Ubuntu 16.04) or are paid softwares. I tried using textract but it has no options of extracting sections from PDFs.

Does anyone know how to extract sections from a PDF made using Latex?

Comment: It might be easier to download the latex source files from the arXiv and then processes them with pandoc.

Answer (score 0):

I have no idea how to do this using R, but if you put all the PDF files in a folder, loop through them and convert each to a bunch of Word documents, you can easily use VBA to do the task.

```
Sub SelectBetweenHeadings()
    With Selection
        .GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToPrevious
        .Collapse
        Dim curRange As Range
        Set curRange = .Range
        .Extend
        .GoTo What:=wdGoToHeading, Which:=wdGoToNext
        If .Range = curRange Then
            .EndKey Unit:=wdStory
        End If
        .ExtendMode = False
    End With
End Sub
```

Or, for more precision, try this.

```
Sub Macro1()
    Selection.WholeStory
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Selection.Find.ClearFormatting
    Selection.Find.Style = ActiveDocument.Styles("Caption 1")
    With Selection.Find
        .Text = "2.3.1"
        .Forward = True
        .Wrap = wdFindContinue
        .Format = True
        .MatchCase = False
        .MatchWholeWord = True
    End With
    Selection.Find.Execute
    Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart

    Dim r1 As Range
    Set r1 = Selection.Range

    ' keep format settings, only change text
    Selection.Find.Text = "2.3.2"
    If Selection.Find.Execute Then
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseStart
    Else
        Selection.WholeStory
        Selection.Collapse wdCollapseEnd
    End If
    Dim r2 As Range
    Set r2 = ActiveDocument.Range(r1.Start, Selection.Start)
    r2.Select

End Sub
```

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know R .. I need to code this in Python :/